# how can I specify the domain on outgoing PHP mail on a server hosting 2 domains?

Tags: php

My server is configured with `example.net` as the hostname, but both `example.net` and `domain.com` A records point to the IP.

If you visit `domain.com` one of the pages sends an email out. I've tried this

```
mail('my@email.com',
'an image (#' . $id . ') has been reported',
'an image (#' . $id . ') has been reported',
'From: reports@domain.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: reports@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Return-Path: reports@domain.com');
```

When sending it to my Live/Hotmail address, it gets sent to the junk folder, and this is what `message source` shows

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com;
spf=none (sender IP is *.*.*.*) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@example.net;
dkim=none header.d=domain.com;
x-hmca=none header.id=reports@domain.com

From: reports@domain.com
Reply-To: reports@domain.com
Return-Path: www-data@example.net
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a *nix server, using sendmail, then you can specify the sender used in the SMTP transmission by passing [extra arguments to sendmail](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) via the fifth parameter, e.g.:

```
mail('my@email.com',
'an image (#' . $id . ') has been reported',
'an image (#' . $id . ') has been reported',
'From: reports@domain.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: reports@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Return-Path: reports@domain.com',
'-freports@domain.com');
```